# Query to find man of the tournament

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has the below data:

```
PLAYER      RUN
-----------------
Kohli       100 
Kohli       200  
Sachin      200 
Yuvi        300 
Yuvi        300 
Yuvi        300
```

I need to return the Player's name who scored the maximum number of runs.
How can I achieve this by a SQL query ? In this case the query should return "Yuvi" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select player from (select player , sum(runs) from test group by player,runs order by sum(sal) desc) where rownum=1;
```

Comment: Its the correct logic and worked fine for me.                                        select NAME from (select NAME , sum(RUN) from SCORE_BOARD group by NAME order by sum(RUN) desc) where rownum=1;

Answer (score 1):

Could you please use the query given below

```
SELECT TOP 1 PLAYER, MAX(RUN) AS MAXRUN FROM <TABLE> GROUP BY PLAYER ORDER BY MAXRUN DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Max function in the column RUN. The query will be,

```
Select PLAYER, MAX(RUN) from TABLE;
```